# chrome.storage.sync returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

### Hello,

I have been recently receiving an error that goes by `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')` whilst coding my Chrome Extension.  Though I have read and modified my document enough WHILST doing a deep dive to find the root of this problem, I am still running into a big error.

I am trying to use the storage to store a boolean that will determine if a button is shown or not. 
 Trying to find the source of the many errors I was getting, I found that `chrome.storage.sync` was the only one I couldn't fix myself.

Quick note: If you respond with plain Javascript, please tell me where to place it as that might be off too.   I am executing this script from an HTML page and would not like it to be in a background script (if that is possible).

My code goes like so:
`manifest.json`

```
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon-48.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["###"],
      "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
  ],
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["popup.html"]
  }
```

`popup.html`: **this is the page where I get an error**

```html
<body>
   <script>
        chrome.storage.sync.set({ "enabled": true }, function() {
            alert('set');
        });
   </script>
</body>
```

`Error I am receiving`: (if you need this)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'local')
Context
popup.html
Stack Trace
popup.html:88 (anonymous function)

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
chrome.storage.local.set({"enabled": true}, function() {     <<<<<------ line with error
            alert('set');
        });
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

Comment: Take the script out of the HTML and put it in a separate file

Comment: @NorioYamamoto I seem to be getting the same error.  Here is the new one: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sync')
Context
popup.html
Stack Trace
scripts/storage.js:1 (anonymous function)
1
2
3
chrome.storage.sync.set({"enabled": true}, function() {
    alert('set');
});

Comment: Remove `sandbox` from manifest.json. It disables all extension API in the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "storage"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
chrome.storage.sync.set({ "enabled": true }, function() {
  alert('set');
});
```